# How to add custom sound from raw folder to to be displayed by RingtonePreference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Inside xml/preferences.xml, I have a Ringtonepreference which allows users to choose the ringtone preference of their own. However, it's only displaying the notifications/alarms/ringtons that already exist on the phone.

How can I add the sound files I have under /res/raw?

Comment: how could you implemnt it?

Answer (score 1):

you should copy your audios from res/raw to sdcard-root-path/Alarms folder, then they will be seen in ringtone select list